# DDEV to XAMPP connection configuration

Tags: php, xampp, ddev

I want to host a DDEV PHP project with XAMPP but I am getting an error, that the databse "db" could not be found.
In DDEV, the values for  host, username, password and database were 'db' but I dont know what I have to write now instead of 'db' to get XAMPP to work. I would like to change it somewhere in the configurations of XAMPP , so I dont have to change my connection.php script but if I have to change the connection.php script it will be also ok. I just dont know, with which values to replace the them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ddev is its own hosting system, so you wouldn't use anything about it with xampp. With xampp you'll need to

- create a database
- Remove the parts of your settings file that might reference ddev.
- Change your settings file to point to the new xampp database, however you might have it set up.

You don't mention what CMS you might be using or relevant information like that, so I can't give you a more complete answer.

But basically, if you know how to use xampp... use it. I think you'd find ddev easier to use, but that's up to you.